# Prove that Taylor Series of a polynomial is the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, book-recommendation

Recently I've asked a question related with the Taylor Series of the Lagrange Basis functions. In the comments someone wrote that the Taylor series of a polynomial is the polynomial. I know that eventually the derivatives will be zero...but I cannot see why we get the same polynomial.

$$T_{a}\{f\}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} { \frac{f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k}{k!} } $$

if we take $f(x) = a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}x+a_{0} $

now $$ f^{(0)}(x) = a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}x+a_{0} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}{a_{j}x^{j}} $$
$$ f^{(1)}(x) = na_{n}x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}= \sum_{j=1}^{n}{ja_{j}x^{j-1}} $$
$$ f^{(2)}(x) = n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}+(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}x^{n-3}+\cdots+2a_{2} =\sum_{j=2}^{n}{j(j-1)a_{j}x^{j-2}} $$

$$ \cdots $$

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1)a_{n} = \sum_{j=n}^{n}{j(j-1)(j-2) \cdots (j-n+1 ) a_{j}x^{j-n}}  $$

maybe we can put this in the infinite sum and see what happens

$$ f^{(n+1)}(x)  = 0 $$

Also we can use the Binomial Theorem: 
$$(x+(-a))^{k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}{ \frac{k!}{(k-i)!(i)!}x^{k-i}(-a)^{i} }$$

These are my questions:

1.Do you know how to prove that?

2.what book do you recommend where they do the proof? Thank you!

Comment: What is your contribution to answer the question? Have you thought about posting the Lagrange Basis function?

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm stuck...

Comment: Good job. I´m almost sure that someone is able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor's Theorem says that if $f$ has derivatives $f^{(1)},f^{(2)},...,f^{(n)},f^{(n+1)}$ defined on an interval $[a,x]$ then

$$f(x) - T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\lambda)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)}$$

for some $\lambda \in (a,x)$ and where

$$T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} { \frac{f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k}{k!} } $$

if we choose $f(x) =  a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}\ \ $
a polynomial of degree $n$... note that $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$. 
For example $h(x)=x^2$ has derivatives $h^{(1)}(x)=2x$, $h^{(2)}(x)=2$
and finally $h^{(3)}(x) =0$

Then

$$f(x) - T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\lambda)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)} = \frac{0}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)} = 0$$ and this implies that

$$ T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = f(x) =  a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0} $$

Thus the Taylor Series of a polynomial is the polynomial.